# K8s secret composition

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, prisma

I am using helm/k8s to deploy a third party ([prisma](https://prisma.io)) container. The container expects a environment variable in the shape of yaml similar to

```
port: 4466                           
managementApiSecret: $PRISMA_SECRET
databases:                           
  default:                           
    connector: postgres              
    host: postgresql                 
    port: 5432                       
    user: postgres                   
    password: $PG_SECRET             
    migrations: true
```

I have access to the postgres password and managementApiSecret as values in a separate secret. I am trying to create pod that fetches the two secrets and uses them to create a environment variable. My currently attempt at a solution looks like this.

```
containers:                                    
  - name: prisma                               
    image: 'prismagraphql/prisma:1.14'         
    ports:                                     
      - name: prisma-4466                      
        containerPort: 4466                    
    env:                                       
      - name: PG_SECRET                        
        valueFrom:                             
          secretKeyRef:                        
            name: postgresql                   
            key: postgres-password             
      - name: PRISMA_CONFIG                    
        value: |                               
          port: 4466                           
          managementApiSecret: $PRISMA_SECRET
          databases:                           
            default:                           
              connector: postgres              
              host: postgresql                 
              port: 5432                       
              user: postgres                   
              password: $PG_SECRET             
              migrations: true
```

This does not seem to work (because the secret is evaluated at kubectl apply time?). Is there an alternative way of creating env variables with secret information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the envvar doc: https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.12/#envvar-v1-core

> Variable references $(VAR_NAME) are expanded using the previous defined environment variables in the container and any service environment variables.

Your second envvar can use the value of the earlier envvar as `$(PG_SECRET)`

Comment: That's perfect. Thanks. I've never com across that documentation before.